# django add custom logger to celery logging

Tags: python, django, logging, celery

I added a custom logging handler to my django app that writes log entries to a database.

```
class DbLogHandler(logging.Handler): # Inherit from logging.Handler
    def __init__(self):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.entries = []
        logging.debug("*****************[DB] INIT db handler")

    def emit(self, record):
        # instantiate the model
        logging.debug("*****************[DB] called emit on db handler")
        try:
            revision_instance = getattr(record, 'revision', None)
            logEntry = MyModel(name=record.name,
                                  log_level_name=record.levelname,
                                  message = record.msg,
                                  module = record.module,
                                  func_name = record.funcName,
                                  line_no = record.lineno,
                                  exception = record.exc_text,
                                  revision = revision_instance
                                  )
            if revision_instance is None:
                return
            self.entries.append(logEntry)

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        return

    def flush(self):
        if self.entries:
            MyModel.objects.bulk_create(self.entries)
            logging.info("[+] Successfully flushed {0:d} log entries to "
                         "the DB".format(len(self.entries)))
        else:
            logging.info("[*] No log entries for DB logger")
```

When I call a function directly, let's say by running a management command, the handler is used correctly. In production, however, the entry point will be a celery task. My understanding is that celery has it's own logging mechanism. What I'm trying to do but can't get to work is adding my db handler to the celery logging. That is, that all celery logs also will be send to the `DbLogHandler`.

This is how I tried to accomplish it. In `my_app.celery_logging.logger`

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

class CeleryAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    """Adapter to add current task context to "extra" log fields."""
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        if not celery.current_task:
            return msg, kwargs

        kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        kwargs.setdefault('extra', {})['celery'] = \
            vars(celery.current_task.request)
        return msg, kwargs

def task_logger(name):
    """
    Return a custom celery task logger that will also log to db.

    We need to add the db handler explicitly otherwise it is not picked
    up by celery.

    Also, we wrap the logger in a CeleryAdapter to provide some extra celery-
    related context to the logging messages.

    """
    # first get the default celery task logger
    log = get_task_logger(name)

    # if available, add the db-log handler explicitly to the celery task
    # logger
    handlers = settings.LOGGING.get('handlers', [])
    if handlers:
        db_handler_dict = handlers.get('db', None)
        if (db_handler_dict != settings.NULL_HANDLER_PARAMS and
                 db_handler_dict is not None):
            db_handler = {'db': {'class': 'my_app.db_logging.db_logger.DbLogHandler',
                                   'formatter': 'verbose',
                                   'level': 'DEBUG'}}
            log.addHandler(db_handler)

    # wrap the logger by the CeleryAdapter to add some celery specific
    # context to the logs
    return CeleryAdapter(log, {})
```

Then, finally in my `task.py`.

```
from my_app.celery_logging.logger import task_logger
logger = task_logger(__name__)
```

But from this point on it is a world of pain. I can't even describe what exactly is happening. When I start up the server and look at the celery log output I see that my `db-logger` actually is being called but celery seems to loose workers.

```
[2015-09-18 10:30:57,158: INFO/MainProcess] [*] No log entries for DB logger
Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
2015-09-18 10:30:58,659 raven.contrib.django.client.DjangoClient INFO Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,155: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,157: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,158: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Timer, Hub, Queues (intra), Pool, Autoscaler, Autoreloader, StateDB, Beat, Consumer}
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,161: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,161: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,164: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Gossip, Agent, Heart, event loop}
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,167: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,167: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,167: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,173: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,173: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,174: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,180: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,180: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,180: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,188: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,188: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[2015-09-18 10:30:59,188: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,196: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,196: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,197: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,203: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,204: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,207: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,208: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,211: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,211: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,212: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,212: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,213: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@vagrant-base-precise-amd64 ready.
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,213: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2015-09-18 10:31:00,255: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: WorkerLostError('Could not start worker processes',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 206, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 374, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 278, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 821, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/loops.py", line 48, in asynloop
    raise WorkerLostError('Could not start worker processes')
```

When calling a celery task I also don't see any logs anymore.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an exception that causes workers to exit?

Comment: The worker loss occurs right after I start the server so all workers should be waiting for a task.

Comment: I am asking since celery starts with task discovery which would cause your task modules to be imported and `get_task_logger(…)` called while it seems to try to access `settings` without importing it first.

Comment: You might be right. When I try to use the logger in a shell I get `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'level'`. I dive into it, thanks for thinking along already!

Comment: @patrys that was the golden tip. I got celery logging to my db handler now too. But once out of my task scope the db handler is not picked up any more. Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0):

set worker_hijack_root_logger to False in config, and customize you logger

[link](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-hijack-root-logger)

Comment: please post an answer, then references.